# Gemfile: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rubygems, passenger

All of a sudden our production rails app has stopped working & I am unable to understand what's going wrong with it. Gemfile is there in the project dir even then it's failing to run the app.

Here's apache log as its running using passenger:

```
App 33785 stderr: /home/david/.bash_profile: line 17: Gemfile: command not found
App 33785 stdout: 
App 33785 stdout: 
[ 2016-11-14 10:37:27.7847 30709/7fb3784f4700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/returns_setup/customer_returns: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 1df05c28
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-cG2Tv9.html
  Message from application: /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_18' not found (required by /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so) - /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
  /var/www/returns_setup/customer_returns/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/returns_setup/customer_returns/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/www/returns_setup/customer_returns/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


[ 2016-11-14 10:37:27.7905 30709/7fb353fff700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:277 ]: [Client 4-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1df05c28. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
We have recently upgrade from Mysql to Percona

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall/rebuild mysql gem.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
bundle install
```

percona dev libraries should be installed to successfully rebuild gem.